# Delete request message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How do I delete a message that requested the bot? Imagine this is in discord:

```
Me
!quote

Bot
'quote........' - someone
```

Then the bot deletes its own message as well as my message.

I got this code to delete the bots own message:

```
if (msg.content === ping_char+'quote') {
    var randomItem = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length)];
    msg.channel.send(randomItem).then(msg => msg.delete({timeout: 10000}));
  }
```

But I don't know how to delete the message that brought up the bot in the first place if this is even possible. My code basically clears the last two messages, the bots and the user's/mine in this case?

Answer (score 1):

[`channel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) returns the sent message (the one with the random quote) and you named it `msg` just like your incoming message (it's also `msg`). Make sure these are two different variables with two distinct names. If you name the original message `message` and the sent message `sentMessage`, you want to delete `message` once the message is sent.

Check out the working code below:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content === `${ping_char}quote`) {
    const randomItem = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
    message.channel
      .send(randomItem)
      // you want to delete the original message, not sentMessage
      .then((sentMessage) => message.delete({ timeout: 10000 }))
      .catch(console.error);
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Ok so I have used your code and added to it in hopes that the bot would then delete his message but the bot doesnt delete his message, this is the code:

`if (msg.content === ping_char+'quote') {
    const randomItem = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
    msg.channel
      .send(randomItem)
      .then((sentMessage) => msg.delete({ timeout: 100 }))
      .then(msg => msg.delete({timeout: 10000}))
      .catch(console.error);
  }`

@Zsolt M

Comment: Please try to read my answer again as that explains what's wrong with your code above.